# what is the different to use the this or function name

Tags: javascript, closures

In my application,I use following codes:

```
(function(){
    var app={
        toHomePage:function(){
            var that=this;
            var handler={
                xx:function(){
                    //now I have to call the clear method.
                    // 1) app.clear();
                    // 2) that.clear()
                }
            };
        },
        resize:function(){},
        clear:function(){}
    }
})();
```

I want to know in the `handler` method, use `app` or `that`?

Comment: In your code, the `var that = this` part does nothing important. So it may cause surprising bugs later in cases where you assign the method to an event handler where `this` and in turn `that` both point to the global object. Don't just parrot what other programmers write. Please take the time to understand how constructors work in javascript.

Comment: In my application,the `app` will not used as constructor,that to say `var xx=new app()` will never happen. Why I think to use `app.xxx` is that use `that.xx` will create the closure,isn't it?

Comment: @slebetman: If I do not use the `that`,then the `this` will reffer to the `handler` object.

Comment: Not in the way you think. To make it work in the way you think assign the object to `app` using a proper constructor which gives you the opportunity to create a closure.

Comment: Also, don't be confused. `handler` is not a method, it is an object. `handler.xx` however is a method. Since the `toHomePage` method does not return the `handler` object it is automatically deleted when the function completes and thus does nothing. The code is incomplete.

Comment: @slebetman—in a listener, whether `this` references `app`, the global object or the an element depends on how the listener was assigned. It could be any one of them (or any other object, since this is non–strict code).

Comment: @RobG: That's exactly my point using fewer words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in a function, `this` is set entirely by how you call the function. If you will only ever call the function using:

```
app.toHomePage()
```

then within the function `this` will reference `app`. However, if someone does:

```
var x = app.toHomePage;
...
x();
```

then `this` within the function will initially be undefined, so it will be set to the global object or, in strict mode, to `undefined`. The same for `apply` and `call`, where `this` can be set to anything.

So likely better to just use `app`, since the identifier is within a closure and therefore unlikely to change its name. BTW, this is a common dilemma.

#### Edit

To explain the listener case:

```
<input type="button" onclick="app.toHomePage();" ...>  // `this` is app.

input.addEventListener('click', app.toHomePage, false);  // `this` is the input element.

input.onclick = app.toHomePage;  //`this` is the input element.

input.attachEvent('onclick', app.toHomePage);  // this is window
```

Comment: In what code? The OP has modified the question to include a reference to handlers. My answer points out that the value of `this` is based on the call, so the identifier to use (i.e. *this* or *app*) to reference `app` depends on how the function is intended to be called, and the differences in how the listener is attached which change how the function is called and hence the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner function *this* will not be the same object as in the outer, so by aliasing it to that you can make sure you are talking to the same object.

in short by using *this* you make sure that you are using the same object.

Comment: Using `this` does not make sure `that` references `app`, because `this` might be set to some other value by the call.

Comment: @RobG as the above code is a function calling itself i.e. in a single context, so `this` can refer to same object.. correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya: The self-calling function is a red herring in this case and has nothing to do with `this`. In this specific case `this` is only bound when the `toHomepage` method is called. See the answer by complex857

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya—The OP doesn't show how `toHomePage` is called.

Answer (score 0):

In the most straightforward case, they both going to work the same.

The fun starts when the `app.toHomepage()` called with different `this` so it wont mean the `app`, and the variable `that` will be assigned to something else with [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or with [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: `this` is not set by the calling (execution) context, it is a component of the current execution context. And [`call`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) and [`apply`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) are methods of `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @RobG: You're wrong: try calling `app.toHomepage.call(window)`

Comment: If people start arbitrarily calling functions with different `this`es, they should *expect* breakage.  Only members documented to work as expected on other objects, or members that don't actually mess with `this`, should be used with `call` or `apply`.

Comment: @slebetman—no, I'm not. The calling [context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) (i.e. [global](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1) or [function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)) is irrelevant. The value of `this` is entirely set by **how** a function is called, not **where** it's called from. There is a special case for [eval](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2), where `this` is set to the `this` of the calling context, but that's not relevant to the OP and is still dependent on how the function is called.

Comment: @cHao: The changing `this` not necessarily a "malicious" act, if you simply pass your function to a jquery event handler, it will change the `this` to the domnode that got the event, this is why there's a [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) helper method to create fixed functions.

Comment: @complex857: I didn't say it was a malicious act.  I said a function that wasn't meant to work on objects it's not defined on, *shouldn't be called on those objects*.  And if you do use it, you should expect it not to work.  Event handlers are intended to work on the object that caught the event, so it's fine to switch `this` for them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that in your case, calling `that.toHomepage` is buggy and you most likely want to call `app.toHomepage`. But if you really want to use the `that` pattern, the correct way is to do it like this:

```
(function(){
    var app = new (function(){ // using an anonymous constructor
        var that = this;

        that.toHomepage = function(){
            var handler={
                xx:function(){
                    that.clear()
                }
            };
        };
        that.resize = function(){};
        that.clear = function(){};
    })();
})();
```

Notice the big difference. That the aliasing of `this` via `that` is not done when the function `toHomepage` is called but instead when the object is constructed. This means that when `toHomepage` is called you get the `that` that you really want instead of whatever `this` happens to be when the function call happens.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why using "that" would be better is

lets say it is a big code base and in your function , you end up assigning 'app' variable name to some other object. In that case, using 'app' will break things.

If you use 'that', you can be rest assured that wont happen as the code size increase or some other developer takes up your code, etc.

```
 var app= {// your module}
 // ...... some lines of code
 var prevApp = app;
 // now lets say you do that.
 app = newModule;
```

Also, it may or may not be easy to detect straight away, depending on testing,etc.